# Questionable Intervals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find the numbers $X_1 , X_2 , \ldots , X_{10} $ such:

$X_1$ is in the interval $[0,1]$.

If we divide the interval $[0,1]$ in halves,each half consists of only one of $X_1$ or $X_2$.

If we divide the interval $[0,1]$ in three equal parts, each part consists of only one of $X_1$  or $X_2$ or $X_3$.

$ {}\quad\vdots $

If we divide the interval $[0,1]$ in ten equal parts, each part consists of only one of $X_1$ or $X_2$ or ... or $X_{10}$

I have no actual idea about this question so any answer is appreciated in advance.

By the way, I couldn't decide on a tag so feel free to edit them as you will.

Comment: Do you want concrete numbers or just a proof that this is possible?

Comment: @martini Yes I want the concrete ones.By the way I think if you can prove that such a thing is possible you can get the exact numbers maybe.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I had absolutely no idea about the tags :D

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMkziQhJkmM and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5q-MzS-lPE

Comment: @JimmyK4542 well this video is relatively close to my question but there's still some problems.I mean the proof that this guy has given is not quite correct.He just chose some "X" without even saying why did it have to be 0.46.I hope someone can give a definite solution to this

Comment: The solution video only showed one case of a multicase proof that such numbers $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ do not exist for $n \ge 18$. For a full proof, the video should have broken their analysis into several cases depending on the value of $x \in [\tfrac{4}{9},\tfrac{5}{9}]$. However, the full proof of that is unnecessary to answer your current question, which only asks for a solution for $n = 10$, as opposed to showing that there is no solution for $n \ge 18$.

Comment: When you divide the interval into equal parts, do the parts have to be intervals, or just measurable sets, or what? Anyway, no matter how you divide the interval $[0,1]$ into ten parts, it's not possible that each part consists of just one number.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this puzzle (posed slightly differently) on YouTube a while back. Here are links to the video with the [problem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMkziQhJkmM) and the [solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5q-MzS-lPE).

If you don't want to sit through that video, they give the following solution for $17$ numbers (at approximately 5:30 into the solution video):

$X_1 = 0.580$,
$X_2 = 0.290$,
$X_3 = 0.980$,
$X_4 = 0.075$,
$X_5 = 0.730$,
$X_6 = 0.460$,
$X_7 = 0.150$,
$X_8 = 0.830$,
$X_9 = 0.380$,
$X_{10} = 0.650$,
$X_{11} = 0.230$,
$X_{12} = 0.890$,
$X_{13} = 0.520$,
$X_{14} = 0.020$,
$X_{15} = 0.780$,
$X_{16} = 0.340$,
$X_{17} = 0.620$.

If you only want $10$ numbers $X_1, \ldots, X_{10}$, then simply ignore $X_{11}, \ldots, X_{17}$.